# Viewbag, passando valor do controller para page razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Tenho este Ajax para poder pegar os dados e passar para a função Salvar itens que esta no HorariosItensController, que inclusive, funciona perfeitamente.

```
function SalvarItens() {
var idItem = $("#idItem").val();

if (idItem == 0) {
    var dataInicio = $("#txtHoraInicio").val();
    var dataFim = $("#txtHoraFim").val();
    var tipoLimite = $("#txtTipoLimite").val();
    var limiteAcessos = $("#txtLimiteAcessos").val();
    var cbSeg = $('#cbSeg').prop('checked');
    var cbTer = $('#cbTer').prop('checked');
    var cbQua = $('#cbQua').prop('checked');
    var cbQui = $('#cbQui').prop('checked');
    var cbSex = $('#cbSex').prop('checked');
    var cbSab = $('#cbSab').prop('checked');
    var cbDom = $('#cbDom').prop('checked');
    var cbFer = $('#cbFer').prop('checked');
    var idHorario = $("#idHorario").val();
    var url = "/HorariosItens/SalvarItens";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { HoraInicio: dataInicio, HoraFim: dataFim, Seg: cbSeg, Ter: cbTer, Qua: cbQua, Qui: cbQui, Sex: cbSex, Sab: cbSab, Dom: cbDom, Fer: cbFer, Tipolimite: tipoLimite, Limiteacessos: limiteAcessos, HorarioId: idHorario }
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado > 0) {
                //console.log(data.resultado);
                ListarItens(idHorario);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Aqui é a função que salva o horário item:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(Horarios h, string HoraInicio, string HoraFim, bool Seg, bool Ter, bool Qua, bool Qui, bool Sex, bool Sab, bool Dom, bool Fer, int Tipolimite, int Limiteacessos, int HorarioId)
{
    h.Id = HorarioId;
    var item = new HorariosItens()
    {
        HoraFim = HoraFim,
        HoraInicio = HoraInicio,
        Seg = Seg,
        Ter = Ter,
        Qua = Qua,
        Qui = Qui,
        Sex = Sex,
        Sab = Sab,
        Dom = Dom,
        Fer = Fer,
        Tipolimite = Tipolimite,
        Limiteacessos = Limiteacessos,
        HorarioId = HorarioId,

    };
    ViewBag.idHorario = HorarioId;
    _context.HorariosItens.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();



    return new JsonResult(new { Resultado = item.Id });
}
```

Na página create, neste método, eu tento pegar o valor de `idHorario`, porém sempre está vindo em `null`. 
E aqui é onde ele faz tipo o "Load" dá página.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var viewDataVariavel = ViewData["idHorario"];
    if(viewDataVariavel != null)
    { 
        HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
                .Include(a => a.Horarios).Where(a => a.HorarioId == int.Parse(viewDataVariavel.ToString())).ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
            .Include(a => a.Horarios).Where(a => a.HorarioId == 0).ToListAsync();
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Já tentei de várias formas, porém nenhuma vem com valor, preciso carregar com o valor. 
Eu tenho a pageRazor Create de Horario item, nela eu crio, e tenho a tabela, que no caso deveria atualizar, após incluir o horário item.
Não sei se deu pra entender, é que o PageRazor eu não consigo criar o design da view, igual quando utiliza-se MVC sem o Core. Então estou fazendo dessa forma.

o ListarItens, é esta função em ajax:

```
function ListarItens(idHorario) {

var url = "/HorarioItem/Create";

$.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: "GET"
    , data: { id: idHorario }
    , datatype: "html"
    , success: function (data) {
        console.log(idHorario);
        var divItens = $("#divItens");
        divItens.empty();
        divItens.show();
        divItens.html(data);
        $("#idItem").val("0");
        $("#idHorario").val(idHorario);

    }
});
```

}

**Edit:**

Toda vez que eu incluo um novo horário item, ele entra nesta função:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
       .Include(a => a.Horarios).Where(a => a.HorarioId == 0).ToListAsync();
        return Page();
    }
```

se eu passo o `a.HorarioID == "Numerodoidaqui"` sem ser a variável,ele carrega, eu preciso passar a variável nesta função.

Comment: Mariana, não utilize o Snippet para códigos que não sejam HTML/JS/CSS em um exemplo completo. Para todos os outros, utilize o botão `{}` do editor.

Comment: Porque quer pegar o valor idHorario no método OnGetAsync? O intuito não é acessar a ViewBag na View?

Comment: Utilizo pageRazor @perozzo, o controller dele é bem confuso pra te falar a verdade, utilizo json para salvar no banco, e no ajax mesmo eu chamo o salvar itens, e então eu preciso que após salvar seja carregado a table, que se encontra na mesma page.

Comment: Você está retornando  Resultado = item.Id no SalvarItens, não deveria ser item.HorarioId?

Comment: Não, pois no horarios itens eu carrego todos os horarios itens where idHorario = o item.HorarioId. São vários itens para um horário.

Comment: ViewData e ViewBag servem para você enviar informações da Controller para a View e não o inverso

Comment: Eu só preciso que a tabela seja carregada com o horário id, o PageRazor é bem complicado, eu não estou conseguindo fazer dessa forma, seja por ajax, na página mesmo.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, podias conferir? Obrigado

Comment: Atualizei novamente; agora, acho que é definitiva! :)

Comment: Adicionei mais uma dica na minha resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Que tal tentar usar o seguinte:

```
var viewDataVariavel = ViewBag.idHorario;
```

EDIT: vi que atualizaste com o JS, mas tenho ainda uma dúvida (desculpa),

```
 $.ajax({
    ...       
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.resultado > 0) {
            //console.log(data.resultado);
            ListarItens(idHorario);
        }
    }
});
```

Poderia atualizar com a declaração de `function ListarItens(idHorario)`? Obrigado.

EDIT 2: acho que percebo o que queres fazer; faça assim: no lado C#, em `Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(...)`, no lugar de

```
return new JsonResult(new { Resultado = item.Id });
```

troca para

```
return new JsonResult(new { horarioId = HorarioId });
```

E no lado JS, em `function SalvarItens()`, troca

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.resultado > 0) {
            //console.log(data.resultado);
            ListarItens(idHorario);
        }
    }
});
```

para

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.horarioId) {
            ListarItens(data.horarioId);
        }
    }
});
```

Cuidado que os nomes de variáveis e propriedades de objetos são sensíveis à caixa, no JS!

EDIT 3: em `public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(Horarios h, ...)`, retira `Horarios h`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(string HoraInicio, string HoraFim, bool Seg, bool Ter, bool Qua, bool Qui, bool Sex, bool Sab, bool Dom, bool Fer, int Tipolimite, int Limiteacessos, int HorarioId)
{
    //h.Id = HorarioId;
        ...
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma ele me retorna que o ViewBag não existe no contexto atual.

Comment: E se trocar `ViewBag.idHorario = HorarioId;` por `ViewData["idHorario"] = HorarioId;`, no controller?

Comment: Só por curiosidade: em que versão de ASP.NET MVC você está?

Comment: Existe algo estranho aí; o método `SalvarItens` retorna um `JsonResult`... Não há como transpor o id que você quer sem retornar uma `View`, a não ser que passes o id pelo `JsonResult`: `return new JsonResult(new { Horario = HorarioId, Resultado = item.Id });` e, mais tarde, use código para obtê-lo.

Comment: Desculpe Marcelo, não deixei muito bem explicado, o que acontece é que trabalho com RazorPages, eu tenho uma página create que cria o nome de horário, e logo em seguido no json eu chamo a div com a página horario item create, e eu crio, e preciso atualizar a tabela, por isso que preciso de passar o id, para que carregue, estou vendo cursos, e pesquisando na internet, porém não estou conseguindo resolver este problema.

Comment: Eu preciso que após criar o horario item, ele atualize a tabela, que está na mesma página, se tiver alguma forma melhor, ou outra ideia, agradeço, quase não acho exemplos na internet.

Comment: Como está o código JS que trata do retorno de `SalvarItens`?

Comment: Eu precisaria entender como e o que recebe o retorno de `SalvarItens`, senão fica difícil explicar! :(

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, explicando todos os processos, espero que consiga entender rs :D

Comment: Atualizei a resposta rs

Comment: Certo! Também atualizei a minha.

Comment: Ele continua sem atualizar a tabela. :(

Comment: Marcelo adicionei o método que ele entra toda vez que carrega a página, teria como eu criar um outro método e chamar ele ? Algo parecido, ainda estou aprendendo a linguagem, não tenho muito conhecimento.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78322/discussion-between-marcelo-uchimura-and-marianac-costa).